# Error while opening port in Python using TI Chronos

Tags: python, port

I'm trying to get accelerometer data from TI Chronos. I get the following error message when I run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\chronos_accel.py", line 50, in <module>

.

 .

   .

raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port COM4: [Error 5] Access is denied.
```

Why is access denied? I'm the system administrator. Could it be a problem with the code?

Comment: Is the code running with admin privledges? Does COM4 exist on your machine? Try checking with HyperTerminal.

Comment: It's definitely COM4. That's what it shows for the RF access point on the device manager window. I assume it is running with admin priv as i am the admin. Is there any other way to run the code with priviledges?

Comment: Are you running vista/Win 7? In that case, the script doesn't have admin privileges if it hasn't asked for them.

Comment: Yep i use Win7. There seems to be no other option for the file to run as administrator.

Comment: @Nick: do you need admin privileges to open a serial port on Windows 7?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I figured it out. It was simple enough.

I just disabled the COM port in the [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) window and enabled it again.

Comment: Had to restart even after disable/enable, but it worked.

Answer (score 18):

The most common source of such errors is the port being already opened by some other application, or frequently by a previous (executed, but forgotten to kill) instance of *your* code.

To test this hypothesis, the easiest way is to run some other program that opens the same port (for example, [HyperTerminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperACCESS)) when you're getting the error. If it fails also, try to find who's holding the port.

Also, [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644) is a useful tool in debugging similar problems with the serial port.

Comment: I am currently facing a similar issue and have verified that in `Windows` multiple processes cannot access serial port simultaneously. But that is not the case with `Linux` system why is that so ?

Answer (score 4):

Another situation that also creates the *Access Denied* error:

The port permissions are actually set to deny normal user access! Some system administrators lock down ports for good reasons, so only users with administrator privileges can get access.

The simplest work-around is to run cmd.exe as administrator. See *[Run a Command as Administrator from the Run Box in Windows 7, 8, or 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/)*

Summary: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, "cmd", <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

"It Works For Me!" (tm)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a port gets blocked.

Try restarting system. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running `python` from cmd as administrator also works for me.

To run:

1. Type **cmd** in search
2. Right-click and select **run as administrator**

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error today in [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) and managed to solve it by opening Jupyter Notebook through [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) Navigator instead of opening it through *Anaconda Prompt*.