# How to close opened port in windows 10 using python?

Tags: python, windows, port

I can control my device for the first time I run python script, however, if I'm trying to run the code second time I have the following error:

```
SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

If I disable and enable the port, the code works again.

**The main question is:**  How to close opened port?

I've tried to close the port using the following code, however, it didn't help:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 38400
ser.port = 'COM3'
ser.close()
```

I would appreciate any suggestions and solutions.

Comment: Serial ports are exclusive, meaning they can only be opened once. Trying to open it a second time fails with access denied. That said, the port should be closed automatically when your script exits. Use Sysinternals Process Explorer to search for open "Serial" handles. ("\Device\Serial[N]" is the real name; "COM[N+1]" is the DOS name that we use in Windows programming.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to @Pourya and @Jaba for helping.

All I had to do is following:

```
from pipython.interfaces.piserial import PISerial;
import serial


try:
  gateway = PISerial('COM3', 38400);
except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
  gateway.close();
  gateway = PISerial('COM3', 38400);
```

Comment: It's not clear what the overall picture is here. Based on just this code, `gateway` should not be assigned if there is an unhandled exception from the `PISerial` call.

Answer (score 0):

As I had worked with ports, I've gotten this error many times and most of the times, the problem was that the process that's using the port is still running, it may be in a while loop, so you should terminate the running code or write your code in a way to break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Windows 10 is different. Although I did  a quick search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105182/error-while-opening-port-in-python). Seems my hunch was right. *(or at least I hope)*

My assumption is you're not running the program with admin permissions. Run it from within `cmd` **with admin privelages** and see if this works.

If not, see if the port isn't just disabled from in device manager.

Comment: You could try my steps, or listen to @Poura. He seems to know what he's talking about. lol